# Error using Perforce within Emacs

Tags: emacs, perforce

I've obtained p4.el and put the following in my .emacs, running under cygwin:

```
(setq p4-executable "p4")
(load-library "p4")
```

p4.exe is the cygwin version.

On running M-x p4-info I get the following error:

```
/path/to/p4.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Yet running M-! p4 info works fine. Probably I'm missing an env variable. Apologies if this is a basic question - I'm new to emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `(p4-set-p4-executable "/my/path/to/p4")` to your .emacs.